# How to add 'joda-time' library to Android application?

Tags: android, adt, jodatime, aapt

I've added the 'joda-time'  library (version 2.3) to my Android application. I use it to get the `DateTimeFormatter` class as follows:

```
DateTimeFormatter myDateTimeFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
```

This works fine when building and running my application from within Eclipse during development.

However, when I build my application for release using some build scripts which use `aapt`, the above line of code results in the `IOException` pasted below. The problem is that the `ZoneInfoMap` text file in the 'joda-time' library can't be found. (It's not a `.class` file.)

**Question is:** why would it be included when building my apk using Eclipse but not be included when building my apk using the aapt command-line tools? And how can I reference the 'joda-time' library so that this resource is retained? Proguard is disabled so it's not a proguard issue.

> 06-10 13:00:59.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 06-10 13:00:59.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28922): java.io.IOException:
> Resource not found: "org/joda/time/tz/data/ZoneInfoMap" ClassLoader:
> dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.example.app.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.example.app]
>
> 06-10 13:00:59.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28922):  at
> org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.openResource(ZoneInfoProvider.java:212)
>
> 06-10 13:00:59.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28922):  at
> org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.(ZoneInfoProvider.java:123)
>
> 06-10 13:00:59.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28922):  at
> org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.(ZoneInfoProvider.java:82)
>
> 06-10 13:00:59.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28922):  at
> org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefaultProvider(DateTimeZone.java:490)
>
> 06-10 13:00:59.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28922):  at
> org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.setProvider0(DateTimeZone.java:444) 06-10
>
> 13:00:59.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28922):    at
> org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.(DateTimeZone.java:116) 06-10
>
> 13:00:59.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28922):    at
> org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.withZoneUTC(DateTimeFormatter.java:301)
>
> 06-10 13:00:59.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28922):  at
> org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat$Constants.localDateParser(ISODateTimeFormat.java:1226)
>
> 06-10 13:00:59.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28922):  at
> org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat$Constants.(ISODateTimeFormat.java:1203)
>
> 06-10 13:00:59.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28922):  at
> org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis(ISODateTimeFormat.java:733)
>
> ...

Comment: Did you add it to the Build Path as a Library (assuming Eclipse didn't add it as a Private Library on its own), in which case you need to set the Order and Export to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue was something peculiar to the build scripts I was working with. In  the build process, only `.class` files were making their way from the `.jar` libraries I was referencing into the application package (apk). To get around this, I had to change our build scripts to copy in non-`.classs` files also. This was happening by default when building from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your production package is built with different ProGuard settings, which are stripping mentioned class. Try including it in apk by using [-keep option](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html).

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, it's not a proguard issue. Proguard is disabled in the build process both from Elcipse and aapt.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, right click in the jar and select 'Add to Build Path'. Just to make sure it worked, right click on the project -> properties -> build path -> Libraries. The jar should now show up in there with the rest of your dependencies.